# I use django auth in my project. how can i overwrite login view to add a remember me view?

Tags: django, remember-me

This is my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from .forms import EmailValidationOnForgotPassword
from . import views

app_name = 'account'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('password_change/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(success_url=reverse_lazy('account:password_change_done')), name='password_change'),
    path('password_change/done', auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), name='password_change_done'),
    path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(form_class=EmailValidationOnForgotPassword, success_url=reverse_lazy('account:password_reset_done')), name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/done', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(success_url=reverse_lazy('account:password_reset_complete')), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/done', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

Is there any attributes i can use like 'success_url' or 'form_class'

Comment: what do you mean by success url

Comment: @byle no my question is how to change auth.login view i want to add a radio button to my login template for remember me

Comment: yes it does @Blye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override LoginView you need to change the

```
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
```

to:

```
path('login/', views.myCustomLoginView, name='login'),
```

Then create a `myCustomLoginView` method in the `views.py` with the desired modifications. Naturally it must be followed by the appropriate custom `login_template.html`